# upload csv file : Degree symbol is uploaded but not displayed as degree

Tags: csv

I am using

1. I am uploading chemical data from CSV .. when I pload CSV file, 20øC is uplaod as 20øC ... as it is (ø is degree symbol)
2. However while displaying the same on webpage it's displayed as 20øC (Non superscript character)

How can i display it as 20°C

you can refer http://webvikas.net.in/advent/msds.php?id=2768&&productcode=90003

refer

WEIGHT PER ml AT 20øC   0.782-0.783 g

while uploading the CSV,

I tried

str_replace('ø', '&deg', $htmlcol1);

Also

str_replace('ø', '<sup>ø</sup>', $htmlcol1); // replace 'ø' with <sup>ø</sup>

with no success

Comment: On my Windows keyboard, I used ° (alt+0176): http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm

Also, you should make &deg is &deg; (need semicolon).

Comment: Dear Sunk818 Appreciate the quick response. Th issue is I am unabe to substitute this character .....I tried

str_replace('ø', '&deg', $htmlcol1); but not getting replaced with desired result ...step1 : Data in Excel ... I cannot replace, Step 2: Generate   CSV file ... I cannot replace....Step 3 : Upload to Database... Possible to replace but cannot do it.....Step4: Replace and display on web page ... Cannot do it... Pls help how I can identify and replace this character

Answer (score 0):

When you are not what character something is, you can use a [hex editor](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm).

For example, on your referenced web site page, there is the data "WEIGHT PER ml AT 20øC 0.782-0.783 g":

[image: referenced web site page]

If we look at the HTML file in a hex editor/viewer, you will see ø has a hex of F8:

[image: F8].

Finally, if you [look up the HEX](http://www.ascii-code.com/) F8, you can see the various ways it is coded:

248 370 F8  11111000    ø   ø  ø    Latin small letter o with slash

[image: header]
[image: detail]

Once you know what the character is, you should be able to perform the search and replace.

After you create the CSV from Excel, I often use a tool called [gsar](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gsar.htm) to replace text files via command line. This is very helpful when you need to perform tasks in batch.

I hope this helps!